# Simple way to upload same image in multiple sizes at once in PHP?

Tags: php, image, file-upload

I am rather new to PHP so please bear with me. I have an issue, I need to be able to upload the same image in 3 different sizes. Now, I only really know how to upload a single image at a time (look below) and would like to be able to do it by somehow using the code I already have created (since I understand that). If that is not possible I am open for suggestions :) .

Upload form HTML:

```
<form action ="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <input type="file" name="upload_file">
    <input type="submit" name="submit_file" value="Upload">

</form>
```

Upload code PHP:

```
 if (isset($_POST['submit_file']))
    {
        $file = $_FILES['uploadet_file'];

        if($file['error'] == 0)
        {

            $new_filename = time() . "_" . $file['name'];

            $new_map = "img/" . $new_filename;

            move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'],$new_map);

            $dbcon = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "databasename");

            $query = mysqli_query($dbcon, "INSERT INTO uploaded_images (image_id, image_map, image_name) VALUES (image_id, '$new_map', '$new_filename')");

        }
        else
        {

            echo "<p>File was not uploaded correctly</p>";
        }
    }
```

Hope you can help me out. :)

Comment: do you plan to upload 3 images, or just one and "make" the other 2 on server side, with, let's say, GD library ?

Comment: Hello Pedro. I really don't know, never used GD library, all I can really tell you is that I will need to be able to take an image and then 3 samples of that image in different sizes (sizes I choose) will be uploaded. What ever you think is the easiest for a noob like me :P .

Comment: I guess you should learn both, but, imo, gd library is more interesting. Please take a look at this php example to learn how to properly upload 1 file , then, I cal help you with the GD library, by posting an example. http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: Alright I'll check that out straight away, tho the php.net/manual and I has always been enemies :)

Comment: By the way, you do know that i mean height and width when I say sizes... I realize now that, that might have come out wrong in my question, so it is not size like 100mb but rather the height and width of the image, that I need 3 different of.

Comment: It wasn't' clear, but I understood that.

Comment: If you want to learn php, http://php.net/manual should be your best friend! Once you understand how upload files (in you case images), [check this code](http://runnable.com/UnF-tFdudNt1AABt/how-to-resize-an-image-using-gd-library-for-php) to convert the images to different sizes. Remeber to make the folders  __WRITABLE__ where you plan to store the images, it's a common mistake that's why I'm stressing it,

Comment: also Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); `then the rest of your code, this way, if you have any errors, php will tell you where they are. GL

Comment: Thanks a lot Pedro I will look into all of this. :)